# Parameter xxx of domain operation entry xxx must be one of the predefined serializable types

Tags: wcf, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I get this webservice error **sometimes** on a SL5 + EF + WCF app.

"Parameter 'role' of domain operation entry 'AddUserPresentationModelToRole' must be one of the predefined serializable types."

[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightwcf/thread/eefb8838-908e-4938-989d-70abdb34404e/) is a similar error, however his solution doesn't work for me.

I have the codegenned DomainService which surfaces the database entities to my client:

```
 [EnableClientAccess()]
public partial class ClientAppDomainService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<ClientAppUserEntitlementReviewEntities>
{

    public IQueryable<Account> GetAccounts()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Accounts;
    }
    //..etc...
```

and my custom service which is surfacing a Presentation model, and db entities.

```
[EnableClientAccess]    
[LinqToEntitiesDomainServiceDescriptionProvider(typeof(ClientAppUserEntitlementReviewEntities))]
public class UserColourService : DomainService
{

    [Update(UsingCustomMethod = true)]
    public void AddUserPresentationModelToRole(UserPresentationModel userPM, Role role, Reviewer reviewer)
    {
        ...
    }

    public IDictionary<long, byte> GetColourStatesOfUsers(IEnumerable<RBSUser> listOfUsers, string adLogin) 
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

and the PresentationModel:

```
public class UserPresentationModel
    {
        [Key]
        public long UserID { get; set; }

        public byte UserStatusColour { get; set; }

        public string MessageText { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("asdf", "UserID", "UserID")]
        public EntityCollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

        public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }

        public Nullable<long> CostCentreID { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }

        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public long EmployeeID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public Nullable<bool> IsLeaver { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastSeenDate { get; set; }

        public string LoginDomain { get; set; }

        public string LoginName { get; set; }

        public byte WorldBuilderStatusID { get; set; }

    }
```

Also cannot get the solution to reliably fail.  It seems whenever I change the service slightly ie make it recompile, everything works.

[RIAServices unsupported types on hand-built DomainService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607973/riaservices-unsupported-types-on-hand-built-domainservice)  - seems to be saying the same thing, that decorating the hand built services with the LinqToEntitiesDomainServiceDescriptionProvider should work.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightwcf/thread/57960ae2-f5aa-4896-89ca-539423456b9e)  will post back here too with results.

From Colin Blair:
I am a bit surprised it ever works, I don't think I have seen anyone trying to pass additional entiities into a named update before. It might be a bug in RIA Services that it is working at all. What are you trying to accomplish?

Side note, you have a memory leak with your ObjectContext since it is not getting disposed of correctly. Is there a reason you aren't using the LinqToEntitiesDomainSerivce? It would take care of managing the ObjectContext's lifetime for you.

Results:

1) This makes sense.  Have refactored out to more sensible parameters now (ints / strings), and all working.

2) Have brought together my 3 separate services into 1 service, which is using the LinqToEntitiesDomainSerivce.   The reason I'd split it out before was the assumption that having a CustomUpdate with a PresentationModel didn't work.. and I had to inherit off DomainService instead.  I got around this by making a method:

```
// need this to avoid compile errors for AddUserPresentationModelToRole.. should never be called
public IQueryable<UserPresentationModel> GetUserPresentationModel()
{
    return null;
}
```